# Changing HeaderTemplate in a treeview on IsSelected with multiple hierarchicaldatatemplates for different types

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a `TreeView` that I want to add two different node types to, with each type having its own `HierachicalDataTemplate`.  I have this working (Code Below)

What I would like is when any node in the tree is selected, I want the template to change for that node, with a different template for BoolNode nodes and a different template for the CompareNodes.  I have found some examples using Styles and `Trigger`s but they are all for a `TreeView`, where all nodes share the same template.

TreeView Xaml:

```
    <TreeView Name="m_kTest">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:BoolNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OpText}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type self:CompareNode}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OpText}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

IQueryNode:

```
public interface IQueryNode
{
    ObservableCollection<IQueryNode> Children { get; }
    int OpIndex { get; set; }
    String OpText{get;}
}
```

BoolNode:

```
public class BoolNode :IQueryNode
{
    public int OpIndex { get; set; }
    public String OpText { get { ... } }
    public ObservableCollection<IQueryNode> Children { get; private set; }

    public BoolNode()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<IQueryNode>();
    }
}
```

CompareNode:

```
public class CompareNode: IQueryNode
{
    public ObservableCollection<IQueryNode> Children { get; private set; }
    public int OpIndex { get; set; }
    public String OpText {get {...} }
    public String Header { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public CompareNode()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<IQueryNode>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `ObservableCollection<IQueryNode>` and put your `BoolNode` and `CompareNode` objects into it?

Comment: That is what I am doing for constructing the data set.  There will always be a single root node and then any number of ancestor nodes.  I have the basic display of the items working with their different HierarchicalDataTemplates applied to each node type.  It is the changing of the template on the IsSelected that has me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work in a sort of "hacky" way.

I added a "IsSelected" property to my two classes and bound it to the IsSelected property of the TreeViewNode. Then, since I only had two data types I was working with, I added a "IsBoolean" boolean field and triggered the template change on those two values:

TreeView Xaml:

```
    <TreeView Name="m_kTest">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BoolDisplayTemplate" DataType="{x:Type self:BoolNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> /*template*/ </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BoolEditTemplate" DataType="{x:Type self:BoolNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> /*template*/ </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CompareEditTemplate"  DataType="{x:Type self:CompareNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> /*template*/ </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CompareDisplayTemplate" DataType="{x:Type self:CompareNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> /*template*/ </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBoolNode}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource BoolDisplayTemplate}" Property="HeaderTemplate"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBoolNode}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource BoolEditTemplate}" Property="HeaderTemplate"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBoolNode}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource CompareDisplayTemplate}" Property="HeaderTemplate"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>

                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsBoolNode}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Value="{StaticResource CompareEditTemplate}" Property="HeaderTemplate"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

IQueryNode:

```
public interface IQueryNode
{
    ObservableCollection<IQueryNode> Children { get; }

    int OpIndex { get; set; }

    String OpText{get;}
    bool IsBoolNode { get; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

BoolNode:

```
public class BoolNode :IQueryNode
{
    public int OpIndex { get; set; }
    public String OpText { get { ... } }
    public ObservableCollection<IQueryNode> Children { get; private set; }
    public bool IsBoolNode{get{return true;}}
    public bool IsSelected { get; set;}

    public BoolNode()
    {
        OpIndex = 0;
        Children = new ObservableCollection<IQueryNode>();
        IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

CompareNode:

```
public class CompareNode: IQueryNode
{
    public ObservableCollection<IQueryNode> Children { get; private set; }
    public int OpIndex { get; set; }
    public String OpText{ get{ ... } }
    public String Header { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsBoolNode { get { return false; } }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public CompareNode()
    {
        Children = new ObservableCollection<IQueryNode>();
        IsSelected = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way I got to work to get a custom style only on selected items

XML:

```
<Window x:Name="window" 
    x:Class="stackoverflowTreeview.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:this="clr-namespace:stackoverflowTreeview"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <this:testConv x:Key="testConv"/>

    <Style TargetType="TreeView">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <ContentControl>
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <!-- This is the default, common template -->
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource testConv}}"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="ContentControl.Content">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                                    <ContentControl.Resources>
                                                        <!-- These templates are type specific, change them for your desired types -->
                                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:Herp}">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:Derp}">
                                                            <StackPanel>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </ContentControl.Resources>
                                                </ContentControl>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ContentControl.Style>
                    </ContentControl>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="m_kTest" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=window}">

        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Collections;

namespace stackoverflowTreeview
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Data = new List<IHerp>()
            {
                new Derp("Derp Root", "Derp Root Value")  
                { 
                    Children = new List<IHerp>() 
                    { 
                        new Herp("Herp Child")
                        { 
                            Children =  new List<IHerp>() {new Derp("Derp Grandchild","Derp GrandChild Value")}
                        },
                        new Derp("Derp Child2", "Derp Child2 Value")
                        { 
                            Children =  new List<IHerp>() {new Derp("Derp Grandchild","Derp GrandChild Value")}
                        },
                        new Herp("Herp Child")
                        { 
                            Children =  new List<IHerp>() {new Derp("Derp Grandchild","Derp GrandChild Value")}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

        }

        public static DependencyProperty dData = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(List<IHerp>), typeof(MainWindow));

        public List<IHerp> Data
        {
            get { return (List<IHerp>)GetValue(dData); }
            set { SetValue(dData, value); }
        }
    }

    public abstract class IHerp : DependencyObject
    {
        public static DependencyProperty dChildren = DependencyProperty.Register("Children", typeof(List<IHerp>), typeof(IHerp));
        public List<IHerp> Children { get { return (List<IHerp>)GetValue(dChildren); } set { SetValue(dChildren, value); } }
        public static DependencyProperty dName = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(IHerp));
        public string Name { get{return (string)GetValue(dName);} set{SetValue(dName,value);} }
        public IHerp()
        {
            Children = Children == null ? new List<IHerp>() : Children;
            Name = Name == null ? "" : Name;
        }
    }

    public class Herp : IHerp
    {
        public Herp(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class Derp : IHerp
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Derp(string name, string value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
    public class testConv : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                return value;
            }
            catch { return typeof(object); }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the templates type-bound, its the construction and location of the trigger(s) that is tripping me up.  Namely, how do I create separate triggers for the different types and type-bound templates?

Comment: This works for a flat tree, but once I add a ItemsSource to the HierarchicalDataTemplates and child items to the root node, none of the child items are drawn to begin with (ie only the root node appears in the tree)